# Switching the solutions in linear programming.

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research

> Reduce the feasible solution $x_1=2,x_2=1,x_3=1$ for the linear programming problem $$
> \begin{split}
> \max\      & x_1+2x_2+3x_3\\
> \text{subject to }\ &  x_1 - x_2 + 3x_3 &= 4\\
>                     & 2x_1 + x_2 +  x_3 &= 6\\
>                     & x_1,x_2,x_3 &\ge 0
> \end{split}
> $$

According to definition of Basic feasible solution, i think the given solution is already basic, please clarify someone..the two concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometrically, a *basic* solution would be a corner point of the underlying polyhedron. Algebraically, since you are in $\mathbb{R}^3$, a *basic* solution would satisfy *three* constraints with equality.

You have 5 constraints, can you check how many of them are satisfied with equality?

Comment: only 2 constraints are satisfied with equality. so how to proceed next to satisfy one more constraint with equality?

Comment: @Kangmin depends what you are learning. Do you know the simplex method? If yes, can you perform one simplex iteration by hand?

Comment: thanks.if i put $x_1=0$ then it gives $x_2=3.5$ 
 and $x_3=2.5$ i think it is basic feasible solution?

Comment: @Kangmin correct