# reducing a feasible solution to a basic feasible solution

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have a doubt in [Switching the solutions in linear programming.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3534091/switching-the-solutions-in-linear-programming) Here, we are reducing a feasible solution to a basic feasible solution. I know the result that in an LP, the optimal solution always occurs at extreme points (i.e. basic feasible solutions). However, what I am unable to understand is:

1. Why is there a need to reduce a feasible solution to a basic feasible solution? Also, a feasible point can always be written as a convex combination of the extreme points of a feasible region, so why reduce it?
2. I just want to confirm that my thought is true (it is likely very trivial, I apologize): We can reduce a feasible point to a basic feasible solution in multiple ways by taking different non-zero variable $0.$

Comment: Your post doesn't introduce enough terminology to give a thorough reply, but perhaps some of those notions are familiar to you.  The tableau used by a simplex algorithm represents a system of *inequalities* by introducing [slack variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_variable) that effectively turn it into a system of *linear equations*.  In any case the *pivoting* rules for a linear tableau are similar to elementary row operations for solving a system of linear equations, with a suitable interpretation that respects *nonnegativity* constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Some algorithms, typically the simplex algorithm, work by moving around along the corner points (because of the guaranty that the optimal solution is among them). This is nice, but to start this you have to find one first point to begin with. So the global algorithm is : Find any feasible point (you can solve this as a simpler LP problem), then use it to find an corner point, and then only move between the corner points of the problem.
2. Yes, "reducing" isn't a very well defined operation. But it can be expressed as... a simpler linear programming problem. Which can be solved in multiple ways.